# Capital ÅÄÖ not printing correctly

Tags: c, character-encoding, pthreads, ncurses

I'm baffled by an issue i'm having when trying to get UTF-8 and swedish characters ÅÄÖ to print correctly in a UNIX-talk clone.

I've set the locale with setLocale() to sv_SE and i'm using wide characters to try to display the characters correctly, lowercase åäö works just fine but somehow the capital variant does not work.

Below is the code in its entirety, i suspect that there is something i'm missing with the character sizes in reader() sender() or putch().

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sched.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#define MATRIXSIZE 1000
#define STACKSIZE 10000
#define CHATLEN 2048

#include <syslog.h>

int r = 0, i = 0, mode = -1;
wchar_t mybuf[CHATLEN], tmbuf[CHATLEN];

WINDOW *me;
WINDOW *them;

struct stuff {
    unsigned int col, row, size, realsize;
    pid_t childpid;
    pid_t mainpid;
    char matrix[MATRIXSIZE];
    char nukeline[1024];
    int nukesize;
    int terminate;
    struct massaskit {
        int writechan;
        int readchan;
        int sockfd;
        struct sockaddr_in server;
        struct sockaddr_in writeclient;
        struct sockaddr_in readclient;
        int c;
        struct hostent *serverhost;
        char hostname[256];
        uint16_t port;
    } bertil;
};

pthread_mutex_t scr_mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_t sendthread;  // Thread that listens to user's typing, and
                       //    puts the characters on the screen, and
                       //    transmits them over the network.

pthread_t readthread;  // Thread that reads characters from the network
                       //    and shows them on the screen.

int srv1(void *ptr)
{
    struct massaskit *sockstuff = (struct massaskit *)ptr;
    int opt = 1;

    if ((sockstuff->sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1)
    {
        perror("socket();");
        exit(-1);
    }

    sockstuff->server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sockstuff->server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    sockstuff->server.sin_port = htons(sockstuff->port);
    setsockopt(sockstuff->sockfd, SOCK_STREAM, SO_REUSEADDR, &opt,
           sizeof(opt));

    if (bind
        (sockstuff->sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&sockstuff->server,
         sizeof(sockstuff->server)) < 0) {
        perror("bind failed");
        exit(-1);
    }

    if ((listen(sockstuff->sockfd, 3)) < 0)
    {
        perror("listen");
        exit(-1);
    }

    sockstuff->c = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    printf("waiting for readchan on %i sockstuff->port..\n",
           sockstuff->port);
    sockstuff->readchan =
        accept(sockstuff->sockfd,
           (struct sockaddr *)&sockstuff->readclient,
           (socklen_t *) & sockstuff->c);

    printf("got a connection! now need a connection on writechan (p:%i)\n",
           sockstuff->port);

    sockstuff->writechan =
        accept(sockstuff->sockfd,
           (struct sockaddr *)&sockstuff->writeclient,
           (socklen_t *) & sockstuff->c);

    printf("got a connection! both read/write  (p:%i)\n", sockstuff->port);
    shutdown(sockstuff->writechan, SHUT_RD);
    shutdown(sockstuff->readchan, SHUT_WR);

    if (close(sockstuff->sockfd) != 0)
    {
        exit(1);
    }

    return 0;
}

int cli1(void *ptr)
{
    /* srv1 starts with readchan, we start with writechan :-) */
    struct massaskit *sockstuff = (struct massaskit *)ptr;
    int opt = 1;
    sockstuff->sockfd = -1; /* make it broken so other function understand */
    if ((sockstuff->writechan = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1)
    {
        perror("writechan->socket()");
        exit(-1);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("socket init is ok.got fd[%i] [writechan]\n",
               sockstuff->writechan);
    }

    setsockopt(sockstuff->writechan, SOCK_STREAM, SO_REUSEADDR, &opt,
           sizeof(opt));

    if ((sockstuff->serverhost =
         gethostbyname(sockstuff->hostname)) == NULL) {
        perror("error in resolving hostname :/\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("ok, resolved host, now making connection [writechan]!\n");
    }

    memset(&sockstuff->server, '\0', sizeof(struct in_addr));
    sockstuff->server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    memcpy(&sockstuff->server.sin_addr.s_addr,
           sockstuff->serverhost->h_addr,
           (size_t) sockstuff->serverhost->h_length);
    sockstuff->server.sin_port = htons(sockstuff->port);

    if (connect
        (sockstuff->writechan, (struct sockaddr *)&sockstuff->server,
         sizeof(sockstuff->server)) == -1) {
        perror("connection");
        exit(-1);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%s%s", "writechan established,starting readchan and", "sleeping 2s so other end can initalize the readchan.\n");
    }
    if ((sockstuff->readchan = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1)
    {
        perror("socket();");
        exit(-1);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("readchan socket init ok.\n");
        fflush(stdout);
    }

    setsockopt(sockstuff->readchan, SOCK_STREAM, SO_REUSEADDR, &opt,
           sizeof(opt));

    if ((sockstuff->serverhost = gethostbyname(sockstuff->hostname)) == NULL)
    {
        perror("error in recieve channel, could'nt resolve host bailing.\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("readchan could resolve host nice shit alabama\n");
        fflush(stdout);
    }

    memset(&sockstuff->server, '\0', sizeof(struct in_addr));
    sockstuff->server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    memcpy(&sockstuff->server.sin_addr.s_addr,
           sockstuff->serverhost->h_addr,
           (size_t) sockstuff->serverhost->h_length);

    sockstuff->server.sin_port = htons(sockstuff->port);
    if (connect
        (sockstuff->readchan, (struct sockaddr *)&sockstuff->server,
         sizeof(sockstuff->server)) == -1) {
        perror("connect()");
        exit(-1);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("read chan estabiled. starting program!\n");
        fflush(stdout);
    }

    return 0;
}

void putch(WINDOW * win, wchar_t ch)
{
    syslog(LOG_INFO, "%04x", ch);
    if (ch == 4 || ch == 7) // Translate left-arrow, backspace to CTL-H
        ch = '\b';
    if(ch < ' ' && ch != '\t' &&
        ch != '\n' && ch != '\b'
    )
    {
        return;
    }

    pthread_mutex_lock(&scr_mutex);  // Get exclusive access to screen.
    wechochar(win, ch);

    if (ch == '\b')
    {
        wdelch(win);
        refresh();
    }

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&scr_mutex);
}

void setupscreen()
{
    int rows, cols;
    initscr();
    cbreak();
    noecho();
    intrflush(stdscr, FALSE);
    rows = (LINES - 3) / 2;
    cols = COLS - 2;
    me = newwin(rows, cols, 1, 1);
    them = newwin(rows, cols, rows + 2, 1);
    idlok(me, TRUE);
    scrollok(me, TRUE);
    keypad(me, TRUE);
    idlok(them, TRUE);
    scrollok(them, TRUE);
    border(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    move(rows + 1, 1);
    hline(0, cols);
    refresh();
}

void* sender(void *ptr) {
    struct stuff *s = (struct stuff *)ptr;
    setupscreen();

    int ch;
    while (1)
    {
        if (i > CHATLEN - 1)
        {
            i = 0;
        }

        ch = wgetch(me);
        mybuf[i] = ch;
        if (ch == KEY_RESIZE)
        {
            clear();
            endwin();
            setupscreen();
            wchar_t *p = &mybuf[0];
            while (&(*p) < &mybuf[CHATLEN - 1])
            {
                putch(me, (*p));
                p++;
            }

            p = &tmbuf[0];
            while (&(*p) < &tmbuf[CHATLEN - 1])
            {
                putch(them, (*p));
                p++;
            }

            refresh();
        }
        else
        {
            putch(me, mybuf[i]);
            int writefd = s->bertil.writechan;
            write(writefd, &mybuf[i], sizeof(mybuf[i]));
        }
            i++;
    }
    pthread_cancel(sendthread);
    return NULL;
}

void* reader(void *ptr) {
    struct stuff *s = (struct stuff *)ptr;
    int ch;

    while(1)
    {
        if(r> CHATLEN - 1)
        {
            r = 0;
        }

        int readfd=s->bertil.readchan;
        if((read(readfd,&ch,sizeof(ch))) == 0)
        {
            endwin();
            refresh();
            return 0;
        }

        tmbuf[r] = ch;
        putch(them, tmbuf[r]);
        r++;
    }
        pthread_cancel(readthread);
        return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "sv_SE");
    memset(mybuf, 0, CHATLEN);
    memset(tmbuf, 0, CHATLEN);

    struct stuff s;
    memset(&s, 0, sizeof(struct stuff));

    if (argc == 1)
    {
        printf("usage %s port        [host server on port]\n", argv[0]);
        printf("usage %s port host   [connecto  host:port]\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }
    else if (argc == 3)
    {
        s.bertil.port = (uint16_t) atoi(argv[1]);
        memset(s.bertil.hostname, 0, 256);
        memcpy(s.bertil.hostname, argv[2], strlen(argv[2]));
        cli1(&s.bertil);
    }
    else if (argc == 2)
    {
        s.bertil.port = (uint16_t) atoi(argv[1]);
        srv1(&s.bertil);
    }

    pthread_create(&readthread, NULL, reader, &s);  
    pthread_create(&sendthread, NULL, sender, &s);  
    pthread_join(sendthread, NULL);
    pthread_join(readthread,NULL);  
}
```

If you want to try out the program compile it as follows:

> gcc file.c -lpthread -lncurses

To serve:

> ./a.out 1234

To connect:

> ./a.out 1234 localhost

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What happens with `ÅÄÖ`?

Comment: Your program works very well in my environment. Can you provide your environment variable `LC_TYPE` and `LC_ALL`?

Comment: You shouldn't be calling `setlocale(LC_ALL, "sv_SE");` - instead, you should be calling `setlocale(LC_ALL, "");` to pick up the locale from the environment.

Comment: Å = �~E  Ä = �~D                                                                                              Ö= �~V Is how they're printed in terminal, as for my env variables. LC_CTYPE=sv_SE.UTF-8 , LC_ALL isn't set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, `wchar_t` is enough bits, and sign-extension problems do not appear likely.

However, the application using ncurses in two threads (`sender` and `reader`), and unless you have compiled it specially and allowed for mutexes, it won't work well.  ncurses (like any implementation of curses) uses global variables for maintaining the screen.  Multiple threads will exercise the library in unexpected ways.

Further reading:

- [Official releases](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#other_versions) (ncurses FAQ):

  > 5.7 (2 November 2008). This provides rudimentary support for threaded applications. It also distributes tack separately.
- [**`curs_threads`** - curses thread support](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_threads.3x.html) (ncurses manual page)

Answer (score 1):

Try using `unsigned char` instead of `int` in your functions.

In putch, you do not need `wchar_t`, `unsigned char` (one byte) is fine in UTF-8 (http://www.science.co.il/language/Character-code.asp?s=1252).

Comment: Removed the wide characters and replaced the integers in reader and sender with unsigned chars, still capital ÅÄÖ isn't working but i got lowercase åäö to work with unsigned characters now atleast.

Comment: Have you also replace wchar_t from your buffer and associated functions ?